# Django REST Framework how to limit user access to certain serializer field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)
```

When being requested about questions, I only want to return the `text` part. Because users do not need to see the `group` part. However, when saving the model, I need to fill in the `group` part for the user.

Here is the serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = (text)
```

If I define the serializer like above, then I cannot do something like this when saving it:

```
def put(request, pk):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)
    qSerializer = QuestionSerializer(data=data, group=group)  # the serializer does not know about group
```

So what should I in this case?

---

Update:

@Anush pointed me to the write direction, the solution is:

```
class QuestionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('text','group')
        extra_kwargs = {'group': {'write_only': True}}
```

Then, in the view:

```
def put(...):
    data['group'] = group.pk
    serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make `group` write only in `QuestionSerializer` like:

```
class QuestionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('text','group')
        extra_kwargs = {'group': {'write_only': True}}
```

learn more [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

Comment: Here is what I got after following your recommendation, `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'`

Comment: @Cheng which version of `django-rest-framework` are you using...?

Comment: my installed DRF is 3.3.1. I simplified my question I don't know if the error is due to this. Are you able to verify this solution on  your end?

Comment: @Cheng the problem is here: `qSerializer = QuestionSerializer(data=data, group=group)` instead try like: `data['group'] = group` next `qSerializer = QuestionSerializer( data=data)`

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I tried this and worked `data['group'] = group.pk`